how to solve this differential equation using the laplace transform?
There was a physics problem and I got this differential equation
$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=g-\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2$$
where $g$ is a constant and $t$ is time. I can easily solve this by using the product rule of derivatives, but my question is how to solve this equation using the Laplace transform. I do not know how to use the Laplace transform on  $\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2$ . I searched on Google but could not find anything. Is it not possible to solve it using the laplace transform?

Have you tried integrating by parts?

See this.

Laplace transforms are more useful for solving linear differential equations. In this case it would merely complicate the problem by adding unnecessary steps.

@MathGuy i will try to use that formula, thank you

@Amogh oh ok, thank you. I am new to solving differential equations


Is it not possible to solve it using the Laplace Transform?

It is possible, however, counterintuitive to solve this specific differential equation using the Laplace Transform. As another user pointed out in the comments, it would simply add unnecessary steps creating more opportunities for you to make an error. It will be much easier to stick to the product rule as you mentioned in your post. In general, Laplace and Fourier Transforms are useful for linear differential equations.
While it is not relevant to this particular differential equation, let's still consider your question about the Laplace Transform of $\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2$.
You may or may not have learned the formula for the Laplace Transform of products. If not, it can be found here. Using this you can multiply $\frac{dx}{dt}$ by itself and obtain what you're looking for. I hope this helps.
